# Error while returning the data from firebase using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i had developed an admin app which was completely working fine,later i released the apk file and sent it to the client after that it stopped working and throwing me error.can someone please help me whats wrong in this.

Error:

```
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.done, null, PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null))
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null))
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.done, null, PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null))
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.done, null, PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null))
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.done, null, PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null))
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.done, null, PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null))
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
I/flutter (21452): AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.done, null, PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null))
```

This is the error which im getting

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2019, 12, 21);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: At first glance this seems like permissions problems on your Firestore. Have you double checked them?

Comment: yes sir i have checked it please kindly check my updated post

Comment: sir should i change the timestamp.date or something??

Comment: Well that rule seems to say that after the date you set no one can access your Firestore. Taking into account that your date year is set to 2019 and we are already in 2020, that would be the first problem.

Comment: thank you sir that was the problem i changed it

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Comment: @JoãoSoares: Thank you for the answer. it solved my problem too